# Delete Selected connections jsplumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I have implemented flowchart using JSPlumb as in the [Demo](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/demo/flowchart/index.html) page. If we select multiple connections the connections will turn into red. Suppose I have button to delete selected connections. How can I achieve to deleted selected(red ones) connections from flowchart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to remove the selected connection on click event of the button:

```
$('path[stroke="red"]').remove();
```